# How to pop the last element from an array of hashes?

Tags: arrays, perl, reference

The following is a reference to an array of hashes. Given such an array reference, I would like to remove the last element always. Will pop work, as hashes don't maintain any order?

```
$arrayref = [
          {
            'F1' => V1,
            'F2' => V2,
          },
          {
            'F1' => V3,
            'F2' => V4,
          },
        .
        .
        .
        ];
```

Comment: What do you call the last element? The last element of every hash? (which is meaningless) or the last element of the array?

Comment: oh, i meant the last element of the array..

Answer (score 9, accepted):

```
pop @$arrayref
```

or

```
splice(@$arrayref, -1)
```

or

```
--$#$arrayref;
```

For some easy to remember rules to help you use references, see http://perlmonks.org/?node=References+quick+reference.

Answer (score 6):

It works. Try:

```
pop @{$arrayref};
```

Hashes don't maintain any order. But you are working with an array of objects (hashes). Arrays maintain order.